# Add background color to a specific date

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I have a calendar and using material-calendar , I just want to highlight a specific date eg 19-7-2018,  meaning it should have a background color eg red

Here is what I have done so far

```
<div class="form-group form-element_date">
          <mat-calendar  [minDate]="minimumDate" [maxDate]="restrictedBookingDates" mat-date-filter="restrictedBookingDates"  [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="selectedDate = $event">
            <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
              <span  class="dot" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day ==19) ? '#348db2' : 'inherit'}"   
              >{{date.day}}</span>
          </ng-template>
          </mat-calendar>
        </div>
```

Unfortunately this does not work

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Think you need to add `[ngClass]` instead of ngStyle. https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass `[ngClass]="{'your-class':date.day === 19}"`

Comment: I think the error is that you check for date.day. Try it out with date.getDate() if date is a date object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the comment you can use ngClass. In the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group form-element_date">
          <mat-calendar  [minDate]="minimumDate" [maxDate]="restrictedBookingDates" mat-date-filter="restrictedBookingDates"  [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="selectedDate = $event">
            <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
              <span  class="dot" [ngClass]="{'your-class': date.day === 19}"   
              >{{date.day}}</span>
          </ng-template>
          </mat-calendar>
        </div>
```

In the css:

```
.your-class {
  background-color: #348db2;
}
```

Comment: nothing is added to the dom neither class or so whatsoevr, I think my code does not work at all, is this the right way of highlighting a specific date in material?? or there is much better method?? :( am stuck

Comment: Is 19 a string or a number?

Comment: its a number, for better refence: please highlight  this date 19-7-2018 https://stackblitz.com/angular/krbrrramqdv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.html

Comment: That is not what I want, U have a calendar inline one , the calender should have a date of 19-7-2018 with a color of red, simple as that,  as you can see when u open that link I provided u can see that today date is highlighted, I want the same but for another date .

Answer (score 0):

try this, **background-color** instead of **backgroundColor**

```
<span  class="dot" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (date.day ==19) ? '#348db2' : 'inherit'}">{{date.day}}</span>
```

Comment: mhh u have copied the same as posted iny my question what did you change?

Comment: try using `background-color` instead of `backgroundColor`

Comment: can you change (date.day ==19) to true and see the code is working or not.

Comment: nothing added to the dom so I think code is not working right, maybe u know other method to get what I want, what I have does not work at all

Comment: create another class and use `<span  class="dot" [ngClass]="{'someclass':date.day == 19}">{{date.day}}</span>`

Comment: that doesnt work : please here is a official demo try to highlight this date: 19-7-2018 https://stackblitz.com/angular/krbrrramqdv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.html